# Prove that the linear operator $\Sigma_n$ on $B^\ast$ has norm $ \|\Sigma_n\|^{B^\ast}=1. $

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

A **homogeneous Banach space** $B$ on group $\mathbb T=\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$ is a linear subspace $B$ of $L^1(\mathbb T)$ having a norm $\|\ \|_B\ge\|\ \|_{L^1}$ under which it is a Banach space, and having the following properties:

1. If $f\in B$ and $\tau\in\mathbb T$, then $f_\tau\in B$ and $\|f_\tau\|_B=\|f\|_B$ (where $f_\tau=f(t-\tau)$).
2. For all $f\in B\quad $, $\tau, \tau_0\in\mathbb T,\quad $$\lim_{\tau\to\tau_0}\|f_\tau-f_{\tau_0}\|=0.$

We consider a homogeneous Banach space $B$ on $\mathbb T$ and assume $e^{int}\in B$ for all $n$. Let $\mu\in B^\ast$ and define
$$ \hat\mu(n)=\overline{\langle e^{int},\mu \rangle},\quad n\in\mathbb Z.$$
Let $\sigma_n(\mu)\in B^\ast$ be
$$ \sigma_n(\mu)=\sum_{-n}^n\left(1-\frac{|j|}{n+1}\right)\hat\mu(j)e^{ijt}. $$
Then it is claimed that the linear operator $\Sigma_n$ on $B^\ast$
$$ \Sigma_n:\mu\mapsto\sigma_n(\mu) $$
has norm
$$ \|\Sigma_n\|^{B^\ast}=1. $$

---

It is evident that $\Sigma_n$ is bounded, because:
\begin{align}
\|\Sigma_n\|^{B^\ast}&=\sup_{\|\mu\|_{B^\ast}=1}\left\| \sum_{-n}^n\left(1-\frac{|j|}{n+1}\right)\hat\mu(j)e^{ijt} \right\|_{B^\ast}\\
&=\sup_{\|\mu\|_{B^\ast}=1}\sup_{\|f\|_B=1}\left|\int_{\mathbb T}f\sum_{-n}^n\left(1-\frac{|j|}{n+1}\right)\langle e^{ijt},\mu \rangle e^{-ijt}dt\right|\\
&\le \sup_{\|f\|_B=1}\int_{\mathbb T}\left|f\right|\sum_{-n}^n\left(1-\frac{|j|}{n+1}\right)\|e^{ijt}\|_B dt\\
&\le \sup_{\|f\|_B=1}\|f\|_{L^1}\sum_{-n}^n\left(1-\frac{|j|}{n+1}\right)\|e^{ijt}\|_B \\
&\le \sup_{\|f\|_B=1}\|f\|_{B}\sum_{-n}^n\left(1-\frac{|j|}{n+1}\right)\|e^{ijt}\|_B \\
&= \sum_{-n}^n\left(1-\frac{|j|}{n+1}\right)\|e^{ijt}\|_B\\
&<\infty
\end{align}
But how can I prove that the norm of $\Sigma_n$ is $1$?

---

This is from page 37 of Yitzhak Katznelson's book AN INTRODUCTION TO HARMONIC ANALYSIS